# Can PHP load a file dynamically with a condition set up in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, include

I have a PHP include that  want to insert on the page when the user scrolls to a certain part of the page. Is that possible?

Something like:

```
var hasPassedPoint = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.scrollTop() > 400 && !hasPassedPoint) {
    <?php
      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myFile.php';
   ?>    
    hasPassedPoint = true;
  }
});
```

I tried that, and it and didn't worked, maybe because the full php page prints out when the page loads and not after dynamically reaching a certain point?

Can something like this be even achievable?

Answer (score 0):

you can't run a php on client side , the only thing that run on client side after page get rendred is Javascript ,

to achieve dynamique using Javascript + PHP , you most use XHR  or Ajax / axios ... etc ,
let say you want to display the data from myFile.php after the event on a specifique element

var hasPassedPoint = false;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.scrollTop() > 400 && !hasPassedPoint) {
   axios.get('/myFile.php').then(function (response) {
       // this is the data from myFile in response
// you display it with 
document.getElementById('urdiv').innerHtml = response.data
        })
    hasPassedPoint = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP (the server running it) has finished interpreting/compiling your site (depending on PHP's version and used methods) *before* you (the client that requested the site) downloaded it and ran any kind of JavaScript/CSS/HTML parsing locally.

It is wrong to assume that the downloaded HTML has any connection with the server that produced it (unless you are explicitly making one).

If you want to load dynamically generated HTML after the site has been downloaded, f.e. in response to any JS event (scrolling is one), you need to request it.

Check [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest) on how to do request the file and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) on how to trigger the request upon doing something with the site.

➡Then, once the downloaded site requested a file in question (your .php), you can run it server side and respond with the result. That process and connecting the **ran-by-server PHP** with your **client-side JS** is the job of your *server software* (f.e. Apache): it acts as a proxy between your back- and front-end code by exposing an interface that helps them talk).

❗ Mind that the code you are using uses jQuery: using it and copying tutorials (the older the worse) exposes you to various issues. Anything done via jQuery can be done with plain JS, usually with minimally more effort.